# how to get value in edittext in an actvity from second activity?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have to register the user in first `Activity`, When user clicks the password `EditText`, new `Activity` is opened to enter password, re enter and confirm password. When in second `Activity` password matches from both `EditText`, the matched value is retrieved in the first `Activity` `EditText` of password. Kindly help me how to do it, my main problem is how to retrieve matched value from second `Activity` in `EditText` of password in first `Activity`.

Comment: make this happen in single activity

Comment: You don't. You have to pass the values between activities

Comment: Have a look at some [login flows](http://pttrns.com/categories/12-logins), are you doing the right thing according to UX?

Comment: @AdilSoomro.....Yes i have to do same thing but i want code and work flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

**Use below code for pass value from first activity to second activity.**

```
Intent mInSecond = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
mInSecond.putExtra("Value", mEdttxtpassword.getText().toString());
startActivity(mInSecond);
```

**Use below code for get value**

```
Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
String mValue = bdl.getString("Value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value of password to second activity like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MatchPwdActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Password", pwd);
startActivity(i);
```

Then you can fetch it in MatchPwdActivity.class as:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String pwd = i.getStringExtra("Password");
```